"No Wi-Fi Adapter Found" Issue
I installed Ubuntu on my Acer Extensa laptop but now I cannot connect to the wireless network because Ubuntu tells me that there is no wireless adapter on my computer. However, I was able to connect to the wireless network when I had Windows installed on my computer. I am now using an ethernet cable. Whatever I have done to solve this problem, I have not been able to solve this problem. Please help me.
When I type lshw -C network, I see this text:
*-network UNCLAIMED       
       açıklama: Network controller
       ürün: MEDIATEK Corp.
       üretici: MEDIATEK Corp.
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:2b:00.0
       sürüm: 00
       genişlik: 64 bits
       saat: 33MHz
       kapasiteler: pciexpress msi pm cap_list
       yapılandırma: latency=0
       kaynaklar: iomemory:600-5ff bellek:601d000000-601d0fffff bellek:5e300000-5e307fff
  *-network
       açıklama: Eternet interface
       ürün: RTL8111/8168/8211/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller
       üretici: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:2c:00.0
       mantıksal ad: enp44s0
       sürüm: 15
       serial: 40:c2:ba:2a:a1:9b
       boyut: 1Gbit/s
       kapasite: 1Gbit/s
       genişlik: 64 bits
       saat: 33MHz
       kapasiteler: pm msi pciexpress msix bus_master cap_list eternet physical tp mii 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd 1000bt-fd autonegotiation
       yapılandırma: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=r8169 driverversion=6.8.0-45-generic duplex=full firmware=rtl8168h-2_0.0.2 02/26/15 ip=192.168.0.27 latency=0 link=yes multicast=yes port=twisted pair speed=1Gbit/s
       kaynaklar: irq:19 ioport:3000(boyut=256) bellek:5e204000-5e204fff bellek:5e200000-5e203fff

When I type lspci -m to terminal, I see this text:
00:00.0 "Host bridge" "Intel Corporation" "Alder Lake-U15 Host and DRAM Controller" -r04 -p00 "Acer Incorporated [ALI]" "Device 161d"
00:02.0 "VGA compatible controller" "Intel Corporation" "Alder Lake-UP3 GT2 [UHD Graphics]" -r0c -p00 "Acer Incorporated [ALI]" "Alder Lake-UP3 GT2 [UHD Graphics]"
00:04.0 "Signal processing controller" "Intel Corporation" "Alder Lake Innovation Platform Framework Processor Participant" -r04 -p00 "Acer Incorporated [ALI]" "Alder Lake Innovation Platform Framework Processor Participant"
00:06.0 "PCI bridge" "Intel Corporation" "12th Gen Core Processor PCI Express x4 Controller #0" -r04 -p00 "Acer Incorporated [ALI]" "12th Gen Core Processor PCI Express x4 Controller"
00:07.0 "PCI bridge" "Intel Corporation" "Alder Lake-P Thunderbolt 4 PCI Express Root Port #0" -r04 -p00 "Acer Incorporated [ALI]" "Alder Lake-P Thunderbolt 4 PCI Express Root Port"
00:08.0 "System peripheral" "Intel Corporation" "12th Gen Core Processor Gaussian & Neural Accelerator" -r04 -p00 "Acer Incorporated [ALI]" "12th Gen Core Processor Gaussian & Neural Accelerator"
00:0d.0 "USB controller" "Intel Corporation" "Alder Lake-P Thunderbolt 4 USB Controller" -r04 -p30 "Acer Incorporated [ALI]" "Alder Lake-P Thunderbolt 4 USB Controller"
00:0d.2 "USB controller" "Intel Corporation" "Alder Lake-P Thunderbolt 4 NHI #0" -r04 -p40 "Acer Incorporated [ALI]" "Alder Lake-P Thunderbolt 4 NHI"
00:14.0 "USB controller" "Intel Corporation" "Alder Lake PCH USB 3.2 xHCI Host Controller" -r01 -p30 "Acer Incorporated [ALI]" "Alder Lake PCH USB 3.2 xHCI Host Controller"
00:14.2 "RAM memory" "Intel Corporation" "Alder Lake PCH Shared SRAM" -r01 -p00 "Acer Incorporated [ALI]" "Alder Lake PCH Shared SRAM"
00:15.0 "Serial bus controller" "Intel Corporation" "Alder Lake PCH Serial IO I2C Controller #0" -r01 -p00 "Acer Incorporated [ALI]" "Alder Lake PCH Serial IO I2C Controller"
00:15.1 "Serial bus controller" "Intel Corporation" "Alder Lake PCH Serial IO I2C Controller #1" -r01 -p00 "Acer Incorporated [ALI]" "Alder Lake PCH Serial IO I2C Controller"
00:16.0 "Communication controller" "Intel Corporation" "Alder Lake PCH HECI Controller" -r01 -p00 "Acer Incorporated [ALI]" "Alder Lake PCH HECI Controller"
00:17.0 "SATA controller" "Intel Corporation" "Alder Lake-P SATA AHCI Controller" -r01 -p01 "Acer Incorporated [ALI]" "Alder Lake-P SATA AHCI Controller"
00:19.0 "Serial bus controller" "Intel Corporation" "Alder Lake-P Serial IO I2C Controller #0" -r01 -p00 "Acer Incorporated [ALI]" "Alder Lake-P Serial IO I2C Controller"
00:19.1 "Serial bus controller" "Intel Corporation" "Alder Lake-P Serial IO I2C Controller #1" -r01 -p00 "Acer Incorporated [ALI]" "Alder Lake-P Serial IO I2C Controller"
00:1d.0 "PCI bridge" "Intel Corporation" "Alder Lake PCI Express Root Port #9" -r01 -p00 "Acer Incorporated [ALI]" "Alder Lake PCI Express Root Port"
00:1d.3 "PCI bridge" "Intel Corporation" "Device 51b3" -r01 -p00 "Acer Incorporated [ALI]" "Device 161d"
00:1f.0 "ISA bridge" "Intel Corporation" "Alder Lake PCH eSPI Controller" -r01 -p00 "Acer Incorporated [ALI]" "Alder Lake PCH eSPI Controller"
00:1f.3 "Multimedia audio controller" "Intel Corporation" "Alder Lake PCH-P High Definition Audio Controller" -r01 -p00 "Acer Incorporated [ALI]" "Alder Lake PCH-P High Definition Audio Controller"
00:1f.4 "SMBus" "Intel Corporation" "Alder Lake PCH-P SMBus Host Controller" -r01 -p00 "Acer Incorporated [ALI]" "Alder Lake PCH-P SMBus Host Controller"
00:1f.5 "Serial bus controller" "Intel Corporation" "Alder Lake-P PCH SPI Controller" -r01 -p00 "Acer Incorporated [ALI]" "Alder Lake-P PCH SPI Controller"
01:00.0 "Non-Volatile memory controller" "Micron Technology Inc" "2450 NVMe SSD [HendrixV] (DRAM-less)" -r01 -p02 "Micron Technology Inc" "2450 NVMe SSD [HendrixV] (DRAM-less)"
2b:00.0 "Network controller" "MEDIATEK Corp." "Device 7902" -p00 "AzureWave" "Device 5524"
2c:00.0 "Ethernet controller" "Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd." "RTL8111/8168/8211/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller" -r15 -p00 "Acer Incorporated [ALI]" "RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller"


Please append you you question the result of the command lines 'lshw -C network' and 'lspci -m'

Okay, I edited my question.

Thanks. Please read the answer of the following links. https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/763127/mt7902-driver-for-ubuntu https://forums.linuxmint.com/viewtopic.php?t=422024 The second one is relatively (xx/06/24) recent an it appears that Ubuntu doesn't currently support the MEDIATEK Device 7902. However, also in the second one is a link to a self build solution which might work. https://github.com/samveen/mt7902-dkms
